# I see my vertical menu twice

Tags: css, magento

I'm trying to create (witch extension) a vertical menu who show's all the subcategories and also not disappears when you are in that specific category ore subcategory.
Till now nothing is working...I’ve tried the extension : Vertical Navigation with CSS Classes.
But this one is nog showing the deeper categories. And also there is suddenly the 'sort by' menu. 
At this point I've uninstalled the extension, but still I have a double vertical menu, and I can't get it away. ([example](http://www.amoro.nl/lingerie/voor-de-bovenkant.html) - mildly NSFW)

In short terms:

- I only want the upper menu
- I want a menu that shows all the deeper subcategories if the customer is asking for it
- I don't want the menu do disappear when you are in the category itself

We have already hours of searching in this item. And It will be so so grateful if anyone of you can help us!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking something similar to this

http://www.overpie.com/css/articles/css-vertical-fly-out-menu or
http://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/verticalnav/index.html

Hope this helps :)